# Text without css tags in Android

Tags: android, html, css

I have an email body and it has html,css tags and I am trying to retrieve only the body text in Android.

I used;

```
String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(body);
```

and that gave me the text with css tags. What should I do for retrieve only the text? 
Result is holding in a String

Normally (when I first receive body );

```
<html>
<head>
<style><!--
.hmmessage P
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px
}
body.hmmessage
{
font-size: 10pt;
font-family:Tahoma
}
--></style></head>
<body class='hmmessage'><div dir='ltr'>
TEXTONE<div>TEXTTWO</div>                     </div></body>
</html>
```

After String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(body);

```
<!-- .hmmessage P { margin:0px; padding:0px } body.hmmessage { font-size: 10pt; font-family:Tahoma } -->

TEXTONE
TEXTTWO
```

I just want to receive TEXTONE and TEXTTWO

Comment: Can you please post HTML example?

Comment: I edit the Html in the question

Answer (score 1):

`fromHtml()` supports only common HTML tags. HTML comments are not considered as tags, and are ignored. List of the tags, supported by `fromHtml()` can be found [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).

Following code should fix your problem:

```
s = String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml(body);
s = s.replaceAll("(?s)<!--.*?-->", "");
```

Comment: "Android does not support stripping HTML comments via fromHtml()." I can strip my text  from html  with this codeline

Comment: You can your strip html tags, but not comments. This - `<!-- O.o -->` - is the HTML comment.

Comment: And yes, stripping = deleting.